# How to change the TabHost back ground color

Tags: android

I am doing android application using Tab Host. I want to change the background color instead of giving default color from android operating system. i google this issue i got some solution and i made coding.

```
 for (i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) { 
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY); 
        } 
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

In this code the first tab getting change of color whenever i click the another(ie next tab) Tab the color will not change. if anyone have idea of this particular issue, ple guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabWidget tw = tabHost.getTabWidget();
tw.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxxxxx));`

//and you have to override

    `public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabId);

        if (activity != null) {

            activity.onWindowFocusChanged(true);

        }

    }`

Answer (score 2):

you have to add a Listener to your tabHost, sth. like

```
mtabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            setTabColor(mtabHost);
        }
});
```

where setTabColor() contains your code.

Answer (score 1):

Because of states and selectors, this is more complicated than you might think. I've found the following website useful when customizing tabs before: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136